# dar focus() ou click() em um campo texto webview C#

Tags: uwp, click

Estou desenvolvendo um webbrowser em UWP(windows universal application) usando a linguagem C#, para atribuir valor a um campo de texto que esta no webview eu usei o seguinte script:

```
string functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('chatMessageSend').innerText = '{0}';", textbox.Text);
await Webview_uol.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

Na pagina HTML o que tenho é isso:

```
<div id="chatMessageSend" data-joyride="data-joyride" ng-model="text" name="text" bp-textarea="bp-textarea" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" class="ng-valid ng-dirty"></div>
```

Porém como o site usa `NG-click()` ou angularjs se não me engano, não consigo de forma alguma dar `focus()` ou mesmo `click()` no campo de texto. O campo somente valida para clicar se de fato eu usar o mouse, via código não esta funcionando, alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

---

O site é o bate papo uol, em especifico essa sala: https://batepapo.uol.com.br/beta/Cidades-e-regi%C3%B5es/Cear%C3%A1/L/Limoeiro-do-Norte/Limoeiro-do-Norte-(2)  apos entrar nela meu programa tem que enviar uma mensagem para a sala de bate papo, já consigo preencher o campo e ate clicar no botão, porem a mensagem não vai pois precisa de algum tipo de validação o qual eu ainda não consegui fazer...

Comment: Muito difícil tentar reproduzir este cenário, talvez se informar o site e detalhar com imagens ficaria menos complicado tentar ajudar.

Comment: O site é o bate papo uol, em especifico essa sala: https://batepapo.uol.com.br/beta/Cidades-e-regi%C3%B5es/Cear%C3%A1/L/Limoeiro-do-Norte/Limoeiro-do-Norte-(2) apos entrar nela meu programa tem que enviar uma mensagem para a sala de bate papo, já consigo preencher o campo e ate clicar no botão, porem a mensagem não vai pois precisa de algum tipo de validação o qual eu ainda não consegui fazer.,,